# How to scroll a UICollectionView automatically while scrolling another UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have two collection views in a ViewController. Needs to scroll the top collectionView automatically while user scrolling the bottom UICollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) { 
    topCollection.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    bottomCollection.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)scrollToItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

displayCell method will called while you scrolling the bottom UICollectionView  . then you can use second method to scoll the top collectionView

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll collectionview to specific indexpath like this:

```
 let indexPath = IndexPath(item: YOURINDEX, section: 0)
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: [.centeredVertically, .centeredHorizontally], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll collectionView using `scrollRectToVisible` method

```
    let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x : contentOffset ,y : self.collectionView.contentOffset.y ,width : self.collectionView.frame.width,height : self.collectionView.frame.height)
    self.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
```